# Prove with holder $\frac{a_1^2}{a_2}+\frac{a_2^2}{a_3}+\dots+\frac{a_n^2}{a_1}\ge a_1+a_2+\dots a_n$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

Prove the following inequalities with Holder.

1. Prove that for all positive real numbers $a,b,c,x,y,z$
   $$\frac{a^3}{x}+\frac{b^3}{y}+\frac{c^3}{z}\ge \frac{(a+b+c)^3}{3(x+y+z)} $$
2. Prove that $$\frac{a_1^2}{a_2}+\frac{a_2^2}{a_3}+\dots+\frac{a_n^2}{a_1}\ge a_1+a_2+\dots a_n.$$

For the second problem. I think Titu engel form suffices.

We get $$\frac{a_1^2}{a_2}+\frac{a_2^2}{a_3}+\dots+\frac{a_n^2}{a_1}\ge  \frac{(a_1+a_2\dots+a_n)^2}{a_1+a_2+\dots a_n}=a_1+a_2+\dots a_n.$$

Note sure about the Holder proof though. Any solutions?

Comment: What is $\frac{a_2^2}{+}$?

Comment: @Gary I think he meant $a_3$ .. It's a pretty well known ineq.,

Comment: @SunainaPati Then please fix it in the title and the last displayed equation too.

Comment: For those who don't know Titu-Engel-Sedrakian inequality see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sedrakyan%27s_inequality)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. This is Holder's in the form
   $$\left(\sum\frac{a^3}x\right)\left(\sum x\right)\left(\sum1\right)\ge\left(\sum a\right)^3.$$
2. Titu is just a form of Cauchy Schwarz, which itself is a special case of Holder.